# JS button with dropdown arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I currently have buttons on my website that are large and act as dropdowns for content. On click a div becomes enabled and shows my content, on click again the content goes away. I would like to add an arrow (something like this https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png) to the far right of it so it lets the user know that its a button with an on click function. As well if possible when the content is dropped down I want the arrow to "flip" so its now an up arrow. Heres what my code looks like right now. Does anyone know how to do this/implement this?

```
<div id="content">
        <div id=dropdowncenter>
        <button id="phonenumbers" onclick="toggle_visibility('phonenumberscontent');" >Phone Numbers</button>
        <div id="phonenumberscontent" style=display:none;>
           <p>THIS IS SOME CONTENT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

css

```
   #dropdowncenter{
    text-align: center;
}

#phonenumbers{
    color:white;
    background-color:#009491;
    border:none;
    width:702px;
    height:50px;
}

#phonenumberscontent{
    width:700px;
    color:black;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:-1px auto;
    padding:0;
    background-color: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry about that, im new to the site and when i hit "enter" it finished and posted my page, didnt even mean to hit enter but my pinky slipped..

Comment: So this code doesn't work? What does it do instead? Maybe it does work, but you don't know because your content div is empty?

Comment: It works fine on my end, i copied and pasted it from my local site. I forgot to toss in a <p> tag in the phonenumberscontent div. Which ill edit in. I dont know why it isnt working at all for you. Im using a Jquery library currently.

Comment: Do you need to support IE9-10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this (link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Konrud/d1kz8btv/)) (here I'm using HTML5 data- attribute to indicate if button/content opened/closed).

I've modified it a little, added data-toggle to the button and data-state to the content below the button to indicate their open and close state.
Also I've changed `onclick` event which now on each click find content according to the button that was clicked and changes their data attributes.

For displaying arrow/triangle I've used pseudo element "after" and added to its content arrow sign as Unicode (which I picked up from [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=triangle))

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
   <div id=dropdowncenter>
     <button id="phonenumbers" class="dropdown" data-toggle="off">Phone Numbers</button>
       <div id="phonenumberscontent" class="content" data-state="closed">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
  publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dropdowncenter {
   text-align: center;
}

#phonenumbers {
    color: white;
    background-color: #009491;
    border: none;
    width: 702px;
    height: 50px;
}

#phonenumberscontent {
    width: 700px;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: -1px auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
/* class for all dropdown buttons*/       
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    display: none;
}

.content[data-state="open"] {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:after {
    content: "\25BC";/*here you can add any image url / sign you want for arrow down*/
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
}

.dropdown[data-toggle="on"]:after {
    content: "\25B2";/*here you can add any image url / sign you want for arrow up*/
}
```

JS:

```
function toggle_visibility(e) {
  var content = e.target.nextElementSibling; /// content element that appears after button
  if (content.getAttribute("data-state") === "closed") { /// if content closed
    content.setAttribute("data-state", "open"); // open it
    e.target.setAttribute("data-toggle", "on"); /// change toggle on button
  } else {
    content.setAttribute("data-state", "closed"); /// close content
    e.target.setAttribute("data-toggle", "off"); /// change toggle on button
  }
}

var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown"); /// collect all buttons

for (var i = 0, len = btns.length; i < len; i++) {
   //// add event handler for click to all button
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", toggle_visibility);
}
```

Please let me know if you have any further questions regarding the solution above.

HTH.

Comment: Hey, this worked great!! Its exactly what i wanted, only issue i have (it wasnt stated in the questions so bare with me here lol) is that the clickable box now layers over my drop down nav. http://i.imgur.com/5rNZtPSl.jpg (see here). The drop down nav on hover is positioned with an absolute tag as to not push my content down but now it is blocked by the "Phone Numbers" button. is there anyway around this?

Comment: This may be many different reasons why this is happening. Maybe you need to play with z-index property. In order to help you here I need to see and understand your code.

Comment: Hey, back after the weekend! I was able to fix the issue by adding into my nav styling "z-index: 2"! Basically just trying to layer it over any content